# Using the correct data structure to return the highest element in an array in java

Tags: java

I have a below method that returns the highest Units based on the return value  of `int []  currentHitsArray = getAdditionalUnits(list1values,listValue);`

My method **getUnits** code is

```
private int getUnits(List<String>list1values,List<String>list2values) {
    int highestHit = 0;
    int highestUnits = 0;
    int currentUnits;
    int currentHit ;

    for (String listValue : list2values)
    {
        int [] currentHitsArray = getAdditionalUnits(list1values,listValue);
        currentHit = currentHitsArray[0];
        currentUnits = currentHitsArray[1];

        if(currentHit >= highestHit)
        {
            highestHit = currentHit;
            if (currentUnits >= highestUnits)
            {
                highestUnits = currentUnits;
            }
        }
    }
    return highestUnits;
}
```

Now I have a situation wherein for each listValue in getAdditionalUnits(list1values,listValue) method returns for example below 
values like [3,11] , [4,3] , [4,7]  and my question is how can I return 7  ?
My current code returns 11 which is wrong

Comment: use heap? that immediately jumps to me when you want to maintain superlatives

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
I have simplified the question

Comment: @information_interchange
Im thinking of a Hashmap but not sure

Comment: this code is far from clear. use Object Oriented Design. not int[] with mysterious contents.

Comment: @PatrickParker
I can't show the actual production code hence I have to tweak the code , The  getAdditionalUnits returns an array for each String value and I have return the highestUnits as per the logic for highestHits

Comment: So you want the highest `hit` value, and for all results with that highest `hit` value, you want the highest `units` value?

Comment: the problem is that you didn't reset highestUnits when currentHit was greater than highestHit

Comment: @Andreas
You got it correct , yes that's what I want

Comment: @PatrickParker
yes i think you figured out the issue with the code but I dont know How I can reset the highestUnits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you set a new `highestHit`, you need to reset the `highestUnits`.

```
private static int getUnits(List<String> list1values, List<String> list2values) {
    int highestHit = 0;
    int highestUnits = 0;

    for (String listValue : list2values) {
        int[] currentHitsArray = getAdditionalUnits(list1values, listValue);
        int currentHit = currentHitsArray[0];
        int currentUnits = currentHitsArray[1];

        if (currentHit > highestHit) {
            highestHit = currentHit;
            highestUnits = currentUnits;
        } else if (currentHit == highestHit && currentUnits > highestUnits) {
            highestUnits = currentUnits;
        }
    }
    return highestUnits;
}
```

Comment: Excellent Andreas , this is what I was looking for , Thank you for your answer and time